# how to put a file in state variable with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to upload a picture using react hooks

```
const [picture, setPicture] = useState();

const onChangePicture = e => {
    console.log('picture: ', picture);
    setPicture(...picture, e.target.files[0]);
};

<input
  type="file"
  //style={{ display: 'none' }}
  onChange={e => onChangePicture(e)}
/>
```

however I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: picture is not iterable
```

when I change the onChangePicture to

```
setPicture(picture, e.target.files[0])
```

the picture variable is undefined,

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless `picture` is an object `setPicture(e.target.files[0])` should do it.

Comment: I'm not sure it's an object or not, I set the value with useState(null), but just using setPicture(e.target.files[0]) still gives undefined

Comment: I think that It's due to the value of picture which is null. And do you think that null is iterable?

Comment: that's right but I changed the value to useState() and setPicture(e.target.files[0]) but I still get the value of picture to be undefined

Comment: console.log `e.target.files[0]`. Is that undefined?

Comment: no that's not undefined,  I get the correct data in the console

Comment: `useState(null)` and then it won't be `undefined`. It'll just be null until you add something to the state.

Comment: @Andy now I just get picture: null in the console

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you meant to do:

```
setPicture([...picture, e.target.files[0]]);
```

This will concatenate the first file to all current files.

Remember to use `const [picture, setPicture] = useState([]);` as to make sure it doesn't break the first time around

Comment: I get an empty array in the console picture:  []

Comment: The first time you would because you're printing the console contents on the current state which is initially empty. Do you mean you get an empty array every time you add a file?

Comment: that's right only the first time I get an empty array and second time I get the correct data

Answer (score 10):

For anybody arriving here looking for how to do it with TypeScript:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState<File>();

const onChange = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    const files = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files

    if (files && files.length > 0) {
        setFile(files[0])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the value directly into setPicture function to set the state variable picture.

Try:

```
const [picture, setPicture] = useState(null);

const onChangePicture = e => {
    console.log('picture: ', picture);
    setPicture(e.target.files[0]);
};

<input
  type="file"
  //style={{ display: 'none' }}
  onChange={onChangePicture}
/>
```

Comment: Can you change console.log line to: console.log('picture: ', e.target.files[0]); and tell the output?

Comment: Try changing the onChange to what I've written in the answer. I'm guessing the event is not being passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

`onChange = {(e) => this.onChangePicture(e)}` can only be written when you made the states as

```
states = {
         image,
         name
    }
```

but when using `useState()`

you need to use

```
const [image, setImage] = useState("");

onChange = {(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])}
```

I hope this solves the error.

Answer (score -2):

I finally fix this issue:

Problem is here

```
const [picture, setPicture] = useState(null); //Incorrect
```

You can use this

```
const [picture, setPicture] = React.useState(""); //Correct
```

This can fix this issue

Comment: You need to import `useState` from `react`